# chart that shows input and output and total

Tags: charts

Sorry if it is a duplicate; I looked around but I could not reach a similar post.

I am looking for a chart that will demonstrate both the input and the output as well as the total. I could use a calories counter as an example.

- Daily intake: 1700 cal
- Daily calories spent (metabolism + activities): 1800 cal
- Total calories intake: - 100 cal

This total value can be both positive and negative.

I tried several types of charts

A. Vertical bar chart:

[image: vertical bar chart]

B. Horizontal Bar Chart:

[image: horizontal bar chart]

C. Pie Chart:

I also received the suggestion for a pie chart but since those two do not make a total of %100 (intake and spent calories) I do not support that idea.

Anyone any better ideas and examples?

Answer (score 4):

I would change "total" to Net Value, since I guess that's more important. My chart would look like the following.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) might be what you are looking for.

A histogram is different from a bar chart. A simple bar chart uses the height to represent the value, but a histogram uses the total area to represent the value.

In your case, you can overlay the input and output histogram, and highlight the difference in their area to indicate the total (net) value.

A rough example of what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think a stacked bar would not work in this case, because one value could cancel out another.

Since you are measuring the same thing (calories), how about using a pair of bars for each day? Calories in and calories out. Guides or a line chart on top could plot goal numbers to see where the bars SHOULD fall if you are following the diet and exercise plan.